# prevent mouseover and mousout from filtering out

Tags: tinymce, plone

How can I prevent the attributes (eventhandlers) mouseover and mouseout from filtering out by TinyMCE?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare those atributes as valid. Use the [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) setting for this.